# подготовка данных в pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как с помощью pandas привести файл.csv в надлежащий вид, чтобы объекты находились в одну колонну слева, а признаки каждый в своей колонне со сквозной нумерацией. А на пересечении, признака и объекта значение, которое указывается в апострофах. 
 Транспонирование не помогает.[image: то, что имеем] и [image: что получилось при транспонировании]
Код

```
import pandas as pd


with open('feautures_90.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        df = pd.read_csv(line.rstrip('\n'), sep=',')
        df.index = ['feature_' + str(i+1) for i in range(len(df.index))]
        num_det = str(line[line.find('det_') + 4:line.find('.csv')])
        num_def = str(line[line.find('defect№_') + 8:line.find('_time_')])

        df.rename({'detector_' + num_det: 'A_' + num_def + '_' + num_det}, axis=1)
        df = df.drop('row', 1)
        tf = df.T



        with open('feautures_9.csv', 'a') as m:
            tf.append(tf.iloc[1:, :])
            tf.to_csv(m)
```

Comment: На последнем изображении то, что получается при транспонировании.

Comment: Можете выложить пример файла и то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе на какой-нибудь файлообменник? [Как задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL / etc.)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то сделать можно так:
исходный файл csv:

```
A_aaaa_123123
b1, "blahbla1"
b2, "blahbla2"
b3, "blahbla3"
b4, "blahbla4"
b5, "blahbla5"
b6, "blahbla6"
A_aaaa_456456
c1, "foobar1"
c2, "foobar2"
c3, "foobar3"
c4, "foobar4"
c5, "foobar5"
c6, "foobar6"
c7, "foobar7"
```

Читаем:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("badformat.csv", sep=',', names=["property", "value","object"])
```

Получаем такую "красоту" в df:

```
         property        value  object
0   A_aaaa_123123          NaN     NaN
1              b1   "blahbla1"     NaN
2              b2   "blahbla2"     NaN
3              b3   "blahbla3"     NaN
4              b4   "blahbla4"     NaN
5              b5   "blahbla5"     NaN
6              b6   "blahbla6"     NaN
7   A_aaaa_456456          NaN     NaN
8              c1    "foobar1"     NaN
9              c2    "foobar2"     NaN
10             c3    "foobar3"     NaN
11             c4    "foobar4"     NaN
12             c5    "foobar5"     NaN
13             c6    "foobar6"     NaN
14             c7    "foobar7"     NaN
```

Далее делаем несколько преобразований:

```
df['object']=df.loc[df["value"].isnull()]
df['object'] = df['object'].fillna(method='ffill')
df = df[df['value'].notnull()]
df.set_index(keys=['object', 'property'], inplace=True)
```

Теперь df выглядит так:

```
                              value
object        property             
A_aaaa_123123 b1         "blahbla1"
              b2         "blahbla2"
              b3         "blahbla3"
              b4         "blahbla4"
              b5         "blahbla5"
              b6         "blahbla6"
A_aaaa_456456 c1          "foobar1"
              c2          "foobar2"
              c3          "foobar3"
              c4          "foobar4"
              c5          "foobar5"
              c6          "foobar6"
              c7          "foobar7"
```

Answer (score 0):

Приходит на ум только решение при помощи костылей. Сначала выделить объекты

```
object_pattern = r'[A_]+[^/n/s]'
objects = re.findall( object_pattern, feautures_90)
```

Дальше циклом загнать в листы листы наблюдения, потом склеить в датафрейм, загнав в индексы наименования объектов